# Mono: Is it possible to run a service on port 80 without root?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, servicestack

Is there a way to get an app to run on port 80 without being forced to run it as root?

I don't want to run the process as root because that's insecure, and I want to use port 80. I don't want to use a proxy in front of the app.

Apache for example starts as root and drops privileges, is there a way to achieve this in Mono?

For context I'm running ServiceStack, but I'm asking in general as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I finally accomplished this using [authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html)

Worked like a charm. Only thing to note is that you **MUST** use the `--deep` switch since mono actually runs another process. That was an annoying *gotcha* that wasted an hour or so.

So final command looks something like:

`sudo -u myapp authbind --deep ./MyApp.exe`

I used the by uid approach of authbind so this is the config:

/etc/authbind/byuser/999:

```
0.0.0.0,80-89
```

**The bottom line** is that trying to find an answer to this question in the context of *Mono* only is futile - simply replace `"Mono"` with `"Java"` in your searches and the solutions for Java/Tomcat are mostly applicable to Mono as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is an OS restriction. All ports below 1024 are *privileged ports* and processes must have an effective UID of 0 to bind to them.

I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish this in Mono, but what you describe about Apache is the way to do it. Often a child process is forked after the port is bound to.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, I've been using Linux for a long time - I know the restriction. I'm asking if this can be accomplished specifically in Mono. In Java/Tomcat in the past we would usually just run on port 8080, but there were a couple of solutions if you really wanted to if I remember correctly. So I'm asking about mono.

Comment: Hmm I just remembered one of those solutions (googled for Java instead) is to redirect port 80 to port 8080 in iptables. So I guess that's one answer.

Comment: [Same question about Java](http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user)